# Two remote full time jobs? -- What should I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, telecommute

I'm based in the UK and have been working remotely for my current company for two years. Recently, I've been exploring other job opportunities and have received an attractive offer. However, I'm hesitant to leave my current role due to various reasons, including the current climate of job instability and the risk of a probationary period at a new job.

I'm considering accepting the new position while continuing with my current job for an initial 3-4 months. This would not only boost my finances but it also provides a safety net should any issues arise during the probation period at the new company.

The new company is aware of my employment at my current job, as noted on my CV, and they're agreeable to my six-week notice period. My dilemma is whether to keep my current job without giving notice while working the new job, which would essentially be for the first two months followed by the notice period.

This decision is weighty because job security is vital for me, and I cannot afford to be without work. I don't use LinkedIn or any public professional profiles that could disclose my dual employment.

I'd appreciate any advice, as this situation is causing me quite a bit of stress and I am mostly inclined into doing this but I don't want to jeopardize anything. What do you think?

Comment: So you plan to defraud either company? Or is one of them offering part-time? Because there is no way you can work 16-hour days.

Comment: Both is full time remote, hours will be the same hours. Company A role is really like no meetings, just me finishing my projects which typically although an 8 hour work, I only need 3 hours for most days and 5 in super busy days and that's split during the day.

Comment: What do you mean you need 3 hours? Are they unable to give you more work after that? What does your boss say when you tell him you're done with the work they gave you?

Comment: I going based on how the past two years have been. Mini projects coming in every day, right? Usually what you see in the morning that's it. We are a team of three on that department that we split them. So usually I can drag them until the EOD or finish quickly and no, no questions asked. Tasks done, you don't take tasks of another department if tasks on your department are done with.

Comment: Long story short, I can manage to work two remote jobs during same hours. Let's take that as a standard. That it is possible 100% in terms of load of work and my abilities. (tech role - coding). Moving on from that.... It's the fact that the current role Is on my CV that I used for the interviews of course. Company B offered me a role. So as I said my thought is if I would not give my notice yet work for both really hard so I keep my performance high on both for 3 months, just that and then give notice and stay with the new one. Advice on that!!

Comment: It depends on the policy for both of the companies. If either one does not allow dual employment, then you're essentially committing fraud and they'll definitely not be happy with it.

Comment: @Da_PythonMaster - In order to work two jobs you would have to get written permiission from both companies.  If you are working 8 hours, and only accomplish 3-5 hours worth of work, you are already performing what most would describe as time card fraud. This most certainly is not your attempt, but if you are only given 3-5 hours of work, and you are say responsible to work 40 hours in a week then either have to work more than 5 days a week for you are not actually truely working 40 hours.

Comment: Even if you only do 3-5 hours of real work, on paper you are working 8h. UK law only allows for an average of 48h per week unless you opt out of the working time directive which requires written information to your employer. No sane employer will agree that you work for 80h a week, and you can't really tell your current employer that you work less.

Comment: True and valid points. You are right. On everything actually. Huge risk to get involved into that situation and judging from all the responses here, I think inside me I knew the answer and what I really wanted to do (TO NOT DO THIS) but the stressed and scared of the change part of me, put that little idea in my head (plus some really not so much to be taken seriously articles of supposedly people tackling 3 remote jobs together).

Comment: On another note though, allow me to disagree with the time card fraud in situations where the employer is not doing it on purpose. I find it outdated at least on workplaces where for example you have specific tasks to do and you complete those faster, earlier or whatever and there's time through your day left, but, you ALWAYS pick up on anything new that might come up, if so. It's not that you turn off laptop and that's it. But that's the case in many workplaces with no micromanagement. I can tell you that my performance is through the roof for the projects I complete and it's just how it is.

Comment: I mean that, yes I most likely will engage in study a new language or code projects for myself, but there are really times that if you finished all projects and none comes in until you sign off, you really can't and no one is expecting you to do anything else, but also there really is nothing else even if you begged for it . So not sure If time card fraud would apply and also, for who? The CEO knows exactly how things are and as long as all projects are taken care of and you WILL pick up anything that might come up, they are happy. Just a side note, and a reason I was reluctant to leave this

Comment: They will know about it because your tax code should show no personal allowance at the 'second' one, since it's already 'used up' (I think I can assume) at the first.

Comment: I don't know hot it works in UK, but in many european countries you cannot have two full time jobs as an employee (but you can have a full time job + work as a freelance).

Comment: @nvoigt In my experience, they tell you "you work too quickly! Slow down!" and "It's only been one day, but your predecessor took one week to finish the same work." They don't give you more work. I used to be ambitious and try to make my own work, take on new projects and such, but after I was told to "do the minimum", I stopped trying so hard to be a good employee.

Comment: @Da_PythonMaster I'm also in a development role, and every single development role I've had has been the same. I don't consider myself an exceptional coder, but I could easily do two full-time jobs in less than 40 hours per week. I could probably do three full-time jobs if I was willing to put in a little over 40 hours per week.

Answer (score 68):

Look, I get it. The uncertainty inherent in changing roles isn't fun and I understand the urge to mitigate it. But this is a bad idea; scratch that. It's a **terrible** idea.

You're planning on "selling" the same hours of your day to two separate employers, and if (and there's a good chance this will happen) one or both of them find this out you're going to be in a whole heap of trouble.

The fact that you are still employed full-time elsewhere is going to be very quickly apparent to whomever handles payroll at your new employer courtesy of your tax code. The fact that when you don't have the P45 for the old employer, you'll need to declare your other income; that sort of thing. Now, that might take a while to shake out (the wheels of HMRC are slow after all). Heck, Payroll might not even think to mention it to anyone (falsely assuming that it was all above board).

But then there's the almost inevitable conflict between the workloads. If you're giving 3-5 hours a day to your old employer, you *aren't* giving that to your new employer, and during the (likely) busy period at the start of your employment that's going to get noticed. You're making the mistake of thinking your situation will just be double your current one—two sets of ~3 hours per day work that no one particularly chases exact completion on, nor assigns you further work when it's completed. There isn't really any guarantee that's going to be the case.

If one or both of your employers finds out you've been cheating them, it's a pretty safe bet that they are going to be seriously unhappy with you—if it’s your new employer (the most likely to find out), they'll drop you like a hot potato.

Even assuming that nobody notices this, it's still a terrible idea. You're going to be working pretty flat out, while maintaining a two sets of lies and that's a recipe for lots of stress, burnout, and general unpleasantness.

Comment: Aaah, thanks a lot mate. I really needed a wake up call to reality. It does not feel like a good idea AT ALL inside me but I guess I was kinda looking for confirmation on that rather than a "Yeah go ahead and do it". As it makes so much sense what you are saying. Just for the sake of conversation through, a. Initially that's why I was thinking to do it for 2 months tops 3, like slow wheels on HMRC, Payroll probs might not think of it as in the past I had left a promotion type of job on weekends as active and my proper job had me as BR (because I started after, but no one said anything

Comment: For like 3 months. I thought myself hey why am I getting so much less money and it was that the promo weekends job that I wasn't even doing it, I was just active on their platform, had me as employed with them still. So I thought, ok if I do 3 months now with the 6 weeks notice being part of it, I assume would get away with the BR part but also 2 months I would be willing to drop performance to company A over B. That was my initial thought (as I would leave them)

Comment: @Da_PythonMaster The thing is the wheels are slow... but they get there. And unless you plan on lying on your HMRC Starter Checklist you're going to have be upfront that you have another current job, and once the taxcode comes through it will be clear that it's a significant/full time one as it will consume your personal allowance, and possibly even push you into a higher tax bracket. Basically there's no way of it **not** being visible

Comment: I'll add that in last 5 years I have sniffed out over 6 employees double dipping like that. All were fired (from both jobs) and one was sued for fraud. Not fun

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's not worth the stress of it nor the feeling that I am lying to people that so far tbh haven't done anything treacherous or bad towards me. And all the fuss and risks involved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I change jobs, I take a holiday between them for the break, not work both at the same time! Even if there's no conflict of interest between each employer's IP, no employer is going to be happy with employing you full time, then finding out you've been doing part time hours for them. Oh, and the tax thing, that's more than enough reason not to on its own.

Comment: @motosubatsu How is this considered from a legal standpoint? Here in Germany, it's downright illegal, due to various reasons, one being, that generally you're no longer covered by work health insurance if you work more than 50hrs from Monday to Saturday and secondly, because your employer is by law required to look out for your wellbeing by making sure, you don't work more than 50 hrs which means they have legal means to punish you if you deceptively work somewhere else in the meantime without their consent. Also, you can't legally work for someone else during paid time off.

Answer (score 13):

There may be MAJOR conflicts between the two contracts, eg who owns any intellectual property you generate when not on the job. I would emphatically recommend not doing this without a lawyer's advice, and they would probably tell you not to try unless both employers approve it (and good luck with *that*).

If you think being out of a job is expensive, try being both out of a job and the target of a lawsuit. The companies can afford better lawyers than you can.

Comment: There's no way that two employers would agree to have an employee working the exact same working hours and schedule either way and you got also a good point about risks involved. I can't imagine the possible outcome of being out of job and having a lawsuit on your back.

Comment: Most contracts for creative workers recognize that ideas occur when you're off the clock too and claim those since they are hiring you for your creativity. Unless the two jobs are in completely different fields, that will lead to a conflict over ownership and firing is the _least_ one should expect. The two companies will probably have to sue each other to straighten out who owns what, and they are very likely to go after the employee for breach of contract to try to recover some of those costs. Whether you can imagine it or not, this is a very real risk. "Career-limiting action." ***DON'T***

Comment: @keshlam Whilst contracts often say that, its not clear on the enforcibility of such clauses _for work clearly created out of hours, not as part of an assigned task and on non-company resources_ (https://www.russell-cooke.co.uk/news-and-insights/news/intellectual-property-rights-in-the-course-of-employment-who-owns-what). Though that doesn't mean they won't try to go after you and force you to spend a lot of time and money defending yourself. On the clock at two companies simultanious is definitely very questionable from an IP standpoint though.

Comment: Laws on this differ from country to country, contract terms can sometimes trump laws (always read and understand before signing!), and violating company policy (and making work for the company's lawyers) can cost you your job whether or not you did anything technically illegal. The only safe answer here is: if you don't feel you could discuss the overlap with both employers and get permission,  don't do it.

Comment: @keshlam This question was very explicitly under UK law, and contract terms can trump some laws, but not others. There are restrictions on what is a valid contract. Within the UK, saying you own all a persons copyright regardless of when and how, probably doesn't trump the underlying copyright principles of you own a work unless it has been done for payment (ie, in hours, part of an assigned work, or on company resources)

Comment: @keshlam Did you have to ask permission from your company to post that comment? It is a copyrighted work created outside of hours outside of the company control. Allowing a company to claim ownership of _all_ copyright someone creates just fundamentally breaks things.

Comment: @user1937198; First, the contract claims work in specific areas; stuff outside those is mine. Second, the company has explicit rules re open-source and the like. Third, I'm retired, so no contract right now. If you don't like that provision in the contract you are free to work elsewhere; if you sign it you should consider yourself bound by it except as explicitly permitted... and two jobs in the same field are almost certain to have conflicting intellectual right clauses. I understand your point, but the professional world disagrees and has better lawyers than most of us could afford.

Comment: (Typo first time was "children Inflicting intellectual rights clauses". Thank you, autodefect. Though some would argue that's true too.)

Comment: I don't see why there would be any issue with who owns "intellectual property" he creates while not on the job. He does. Why would the company be able to claim ownership of stuff he does on his own free time?

Comment: @RuslanOblov: Clauses agreeing to that are common in employment contracts for knowledge workers in the US. I can't vouch for whether that's true elsewhere. If you don't sign the contract you don't get the job; if you do sign it unchanged then you are bound by it at least to the extent of their being able to fire you for violating it and often more than that. I have seen someone fired on the spot and escorted off-site for intellectual property rights violation., and that wasn't  even a case where the company's own rights were put at risk. NOT a good bet to make without a lawyer's advice.

Comment: @keshlam That's exactly why I've never been able to help my friends with their coding projects or teach coding classes in my free time. My employer could claim all that work as theirs. There's so much more I want to do, but I will have to wait until retirement.

Comment: As previously noted, IBM was reasonable about this -- strict contract saying they could, policy saying that for most personal projects which didn't directly compete with products they wouldn't.

Comment: But IBM was a *civilized* employer.

Comment: Those clauses are absurd and likely unenforceable in most countries. If they want to own the code I produce when I'm off the clock then they should pay for it. You're not at work 24/7. 

Also, I have no idea how that could ever even come to the attention of whatever company that put this clause in a contract.

Comment: Absurd or not, they are enforceable in some countries, and in places with at-will employment they an adequate reason for management to fire you for cause even if they can't press suit. If you know you're safe, do what you want, though I still think trying to hold down two full time jobs and perform adequately in both is a recipe for disaster unless there is no other way to support yourself (and even then is going to destroy your health). And if you think you can hide it, I think you're fooling yourself. But you do you; good luck; you're going to need it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, read your employment contract with your present employer to see if taking a side job (both in general, and this job in specific) violates the terms of your current contract.  (For a personal example, (I'm a tech worker) I could get permission to take a night/weekend job teaching fitness classes, but I could not get permission to take a second job at another tech firm.)

Secondly, make sure that your new employer understands that you will be signing on with them as a second job, at least at first.  (And get this understanding in writing!)

Thirdly, make sure that the hours each employer expects you to be available do not overlap. There are enough stories floating around about remote workers double dipping that people will be suspicious if you are suddenly unavailable or distracted in meetings during core working hours.

Finally, while many people do work 80 hour weeks to make ends meet, or as part of an on/off rotation, it is **exhausting**, and will likely cut into your performance.  You may well find that at the end of a few months you have some extra money but do not pass probation at the new job and are put on performance review at your current job.

As an alternative, still deep in an ethical gray area, you could take a leave of absence at your current job and try out the new job; that might give you a fall back if the new job does not work out, or, again, could get you in trouble in both places and even possibly the target of industry gossip that affects your job prospects in the future.  (This depends, of course, on how small your field is.)